# Relative Height in Cesium

Tags: cesiumjs

**EDIT: just realized that I pass a single coordinate while it expects an array. Will check and update.**

Need to place a model on the ground (water).

As I understood, relative heights (as `relativeToGround` in KML) are not yet implemented. So, for now the best solution is to ask terrain provider for terrain height at a location and adjust model's height accordingly [[1](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=Hello%20World.html&label=undefined)] (and than handle changing level-of-detail somehow).

Here is simple example for [Sandcastle](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=Hello%20World.html&label=undefined). 
I just try to get a height for a location.
I expect `Cesium.sampleTerrain` to return a `promise` which than resolves with `Cartographic` having it's `height` modified to terrain height at the location.
But it just immediately (synchronously?) resolves with unmodified input (`height == 100`).

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');

viewer.terrainProvider = 
    new Cesium.CesiumTerrainProvider({ url : '//cesiumjs.org/stk-terrain/tilesets/world/tiles' })
//    new Cesium.CesiumTerrainProvider({ url : '//cesiumjs.org/tilesets/terrain/smallterrain' })
//    new Cesium.VRTheWorldTerrainProvider({ url : '//www.vr-theworld.com/vr-theworld/tiles1.0.0/73/' })
//    new Cesium.EllipsoidTerrainProvider()
;

viewer.camera.flyTo({ 
    destination: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromRadians(2.5269731598108605, -0.669099684580548, 100)
  , duration: 0 
});

Cesium.sampleTerrain(viewer.terrainProvider, 11, viewer.camera.positionCartographic.clone())
.then(function(x) { console.log(x) })
;
```

1. What's wrong with the code?
2. Is there any alternative approach?

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you've answered your own question.  Adding square brackets around the 3rd parameter to Cesium.sampleTerrain() does fix the output of this code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript below to fill an array of positions with their altitudes :

```
var cartographicPositions = Cesium.Ellipsoid.WGS84.cartesianArrayToCartographicArray(points);
// points are an array of positions(x,y,0)
                var HeightCheck=setInterval(function(){
                        if (cesiumTerrainProviderHeightmaps.ready)
                        {
                            clearInterval(HeightCheck);
                            $("#info2a").html("ok wait :)" );
                            var promise = Cesium.sampleTerrain(cesiumTerrainProviderHeightmaps, 11, cartographicPositions);
                            Cesium.when(promise, function(cartographicPositions) {
                                    $("#info2a").html("ok got the altitudes" );

                                });
                        } else {
                            $("#info2a").html("Waiting for height data of terrain...." );
                        }
                    },1000);
```